# Determine Difference Of Decimal Sequence Dynamically

Tags: r, floating-point, sequence

I need to determine the difference of a given sequence of decimal numbers dynamically. Given the sequence:

```
my_seq <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)
```

Where 0.1 can be any decimal (0.01, 0.5), but am using 0.1 for the sake of example. My attempt to determine that the granularity is 0.1 is:

```
# Generating sequence.
my_seq <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)

# Attempting to find difference.
uni_diff <- unique(diff(my_seq))
print(uni_diff) # Will be multiple, due to floating point behavior.

# Printing out uni_diff for visualization.
print(sprintf("%.54f", uni_diff))
```

As noted at the end, my differentiating fails due how floating point numbers are handled in computers, see "Circle 1" in the R Inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Is there any reliable way to do this? I can force the user to tell me the granularity, which works, but would like to be able to determine from the given sequence automatically.

EDIT:

To further illustrate my problem. Let's say I gave you:

```
x = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
```

And then asked how to determine that 0.1 is the difference between each number. How would this be done? It's trivial for integers, but not for floating points it seems.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand: are you trying to find *exactly* 0.1? It doesn't exist. To convince yourself run `print(sprintf("%.54f", 0.1))`.

Comment: If you are concerned about a "good" value to handle minor round-off differences try `mean(diff(my_seq))`

Comment: I'm trying to determine what the "by" is from a given decimal sequence. For example, if given (0.1, 0.2, 0.3) how much are these segmented by? Floating point issues make this difficult. I don't know 0.1 ahead of time.

Comment: Taking the mean seems like a good solution. Will use that. Thanks, feel free to throw an answer.

Comment: Yes,  there is no good answer. Following up on the comment of @RuiBarradas   try `print(sprintf("%.32f", diff(my_seq)))`   There is no perfect binary representation of 0.1 so you will get some variation.

Comment: I agree, I knew this, evidenced by my example script, but don't think I was quite appreciating that reality. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact representation of 0.1 as a floating point number,  so you will not get a precise answer. Following the comment of @RuiBarradas,  you could print out the differences with high precision and see the variation

```
## print(sprintf("%.32f", diff(my_seq)))        
## This will produce too much output

table(sprintf("%.32f", diff(my_seq)))

0.09999999999999964472863211994991 0.09999999999999986677323704498122 
                                44                                  4 
0.09999999999999997779553950749687 0.10000000000000000555111512312578 
                                 6                                  2 
0.10000000000000003330669073875470 0.10000000000000008881784197001252 
                                 1                                 23 
0.10000000000000053290705182007514 0.10000000000000142108547152020037 
                                16                                  4
```

Since you get many similar representations of 0.1,  it may be best to use `mean(diff(my_seq))`

```
sprintf("%.32f", mean(diff(my_seq)))
[1] "0.10000000000000000555111512312578"
```